# ICU support without v8_enable_i18n_support flag

Tags: v8, intl, dayjs

I am working on a project which uses v8 to create a javascript-runtime. I compile v8 as a static library and am using cmakelists.txt for compilation/linking purposes.

I have compiled v8 as static library with flag `v8_enable_i18n_support = false` in my args.gn
Is it possible to have the intl support with adding the ICU files in project directory and linking it in cmakelists.txt file that i am using for compiling.

I am not sure how intl support works for v8. Lets say if i had compiled v8 with `v8_enable_i18n_support = true` in my args.gn would i still need to link the icu files in my project directory? Like in the project here we see both v8 and icu files being linked in cmake
[ref project](https://github.com/weinberger/arangodb/blob/37f52fd42f947e542705f2b84dbfe39647bd0e16/CMakeLists.txt#L609)

Tried compiling v8 with **v8_enable_i18n_support = false** but still when trying to use a function (a dayjs library method which needs intl support) i do get error intl not defined suggesting that it lack ICU support ( please correct if my understanding is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

`v8_enable_i18n_support = false` turns off ICU support in V8, that is the purpose of that flag.

If you want ICU support, compile with `v8_enable_i18n_support = true` (which is also the default, I think). V8's build system handles everything for you; when using your own build system, you will need to provide ICU for linking (statically or dynamically, both should work).